# Flask: заполнение внешнего ключа автоматически

Tags: python-3.x, flask, sqlalchemy

Возможно глупо прозвучит, но уже голову сломал, как избавиться от необходимости заполнять внешний ключ вручную.
Дано:

models.py

```
# -*- coding: utf-8 -*-
from datetime import date
from app import db

class Article(db.Model):
    id = db.Column(db.Integer, primary_key=True, autoincrement=True)
    data = db.Column(db.Date, default=date.today)
    title = db.Column(db.String(120), nullable=False)
    first_post = db.Column(db.String(120), nullable=False)



class Comment(db.Model):
    id = db.Column(db.Integer, primary_key=True, autoincrement=True)

    article_id = db.Column(
        db.Integer,
        db.ForeignKey('article.id'),
        nullable=False,
        index=True
     )

    article = db.relationship(Article, foreign_keys=[article_id, ])

    post = db.Column(db.String(120), nullable=False)
    data = db.Column(db.Date, default=date.today)
```

app.py

```
@blueprint_page.route('/comment', methods=['POST', ])
def comment(id=global_id):
    from models import Comment, Article
    from forms import CommentForm

    if request.method == 'POST':
        form = CommentForm(request.form)
        if form.validate():
            com = Comment(**form.data)
            db.session.add(com)
            db.session.commit()
            flash('Comment added!')
            return art(id)
        else:
            flash('Connot to add a comment!')
            flash(str(form.errors))
            return 'Connot to add a comment!' + str(form.errors)
```

Чтобы добавить значение внешнего ключа, использую поле в форме:

```
<div class="form-group">
                <label for="article_id">ID</label>
                <input type="text" class="form-control" id="article_id" name="article_id">
            </div>
```

Более подробная форма:

```
<form action="{{ url_for('.comment') }}" method="POST" name="comment" id="comment">
        <div class="form-group">
            <label for="post">Post:</label>
            <textarea class="form-control" rows="5" id="post" name="post"></textarea>
        </div>
        <div class="form-group">
                <label for="article_id">ID</label>
                <input type="text" class="form-control" id="article_id" name="article_id">
            </div>
        <button type="submit" class="btn btn-primary">Submit</button>
    </form>
```

Как избавиться от необходимости самостоятельно заполнять это поле, а чтобы все это выставлялось автоматически? 
Спасибо.

Comment: После `com = Comment(**form.data)` в `app.py` добавьте `com.article_id = id`.

Comment: @floydya, да, это я тоже пробовал. Но выводит ошибку при проверки на валидацию формы: "Connot to add a comment!{'article_id': ['This field is required.']}"

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Утро вечера мудренее. Я взял за основу ответ @floydya, что б добавить код `com.article_id = id` после `com = Comment(**form.data)` в `app.py`. А от себя в `model.py` изменил значение модели `article_id` с `nullable=False` на `True`. Теперь все заработало, как и планировалось.